# Entity Framework not inserting record

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework

I'm working on a small project in WPF where you can insert, edit and search Recipes. I'm using Entity for this.

Recipe has a property, `list<Ingredient>`. When I insert an ingredient, it's OK, but when I insert a recipe with a `list<Ingredient>`, everything is ok except that in table recipe, there is no column ingredient at all. But in debug I clearly can see that in my method where I insert a recipe , the object recipe has ingredients count... I have spend couple hours trying different things out but with no luck.

This is how I insert (same as ingredient , where everything works)

```
public static void InsertRecipe(Recipe recipe)
{
    RecipeDbContext ctx = new RecipeDbContext();
    ctx.Recipes.Add(recipe);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Screen-shots from debug:

[Recipe Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlDKt.png)

[Recipe object properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxyPv.png)

[image: Populate a list<Ingredients> from ingredients in DB to add it to the new Recipe]
Just for testing purposes , the ingredients should come from a listbox later on.
When I press ctrl property menu is fading away (reason why screen-shot is the way it is)

Comment: we need more détails. do you get any exception? use SQL Profiler to see the insert query.

Comment: No not any exception , everything gets inserted well except the list of ingredients , it doesn't even create a colomn for it  ... I have a list of DbSets for Recipe and ingredient. I don't kwow "SQL Profiler" im gonna check out what that is an try it.

Comment: I have checked out SQL Profiler , i can't go and try all this since this will take me more time than i have to submit this project . I have to give it in tomorrow.I can however provide you with more details , screenshots or anything you need.

Comment: you are trying to insert an object with list? can you please put your code, it's not clear for me

Comment: Yes thats it , i editted my above post. Object recipe has a property List<Ingredient> , so in that way i populate that list ,set the other properties values and then insert the recipe.

Comment: I think you cann't do that. You must insert recipe item and after that  insert all ingrédients one by one.

Comment: Thank you that must be the issue , i didn't even thought that could be it.But how can i achieve this , i know how to loop through it but i can't insert it into table ingredients as it have to be part of the recipe.Ingredients.So how can i insert each ingredient to that 1 recipe record ?Thank you for your time Amine !

Comment: I think you have two tables, and in Ingredient table you have a foreign key of recipe. that's it?

Comment: Yes there are 2 tables indeed.I have a DbSet of Ingredients , and Dbset of Recipe ,I also have a class RecipeIngredient , i think this is what your talking about , this table contains recipeID and ingredient ID ,My class Ingredient has a property int Id , so does my class Recipe , Class Ingredient has a property of type Recipe and class Recipe has a property List<Ingredients> .They should be connected to each other.

Comment: What is the **connection string** your project is using?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Username\Desktop\RecipeProject\Recipes\bin\Debug\RecipeDataBase.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must insert Recipe item and get the ID :

```
public static int InsertRecipe(Recipe recipe)
            {
                RecipeDbContext ctx = new RecipeDbContext();
                ctx.Recipes.Add(recipe);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return recipe.recipeID;
            }
```

And after that you can insert all Ingrédients, Something like that

```
public static void InsertIngredient(List<Ingredient> Ingredients, int recipeID)
        {
            IngredientDbContext ctx = new IngredientDbContext();

            foreach (var ingredient in Ingredients)
            {
                Ingredient newItem = new Ingredient { IngredientID = ingredient.Ingredient,..., recipeID = recipeID};
                ctx.Ingredient.Add(newItem);
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Ok i understand it now thanx for explaining that to me.I can't reach the ingredient.Recipe.recipeID ... says that Ingredient doesn't contain a defenition for recipeID ... im so frustrated as this should be a simple thing and im not getting how to achieve this .

Comment: @ marc_s , thank you for your time , it is the correct Database , i can see each new record in that , problem is that from all the properties a recipe has , it inserts all except ingredient(list). so i think what Amine is explaining should do it , just don't know how to excactly do it ... As for your steps , 1 and 2 i already have , so im gonna try this approach from now on ,im in school for now so thats the reason mdf is sufficient . i do understand that there are much better/more stable alternatives like yours.Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `RecipeDataBase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RecipeDataBase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.